# Call static function on array of types

Tags: php

For example, I got the following classes: `\App\User`, `\App\Profile` and `\App\Icon`.
Every class got a static function `creating` which accepts a closure as paramter.
Now I got an array of them:

```
$classes = [
   \App\User::class,
   \App\Profile::class,
   \App\Icon:class
];
```

Now I want to loop trough the array and call the `creating` function with a closure on every class.
My problem is that I don't know much about the `::class` keyword and how to use it proberly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::class` will just return the fully-qualified class name.

```
$classes = [
\App\User::class,
\App\Profile::class,
\App\Icon::class
];
```

Is the same (effectively) as:

```
$classes = [
   "\App\User",
   "\App\Profile",
   "App\Icon"
];
```

So it's iterable just like normal dynamic class names:

```
foreach($classes as $class){
   $class::creating($closure);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would operate with the class names. Without having tried:

```
$classes = [
   'User',
   'Profile',
   'Icon'
];
foreach ($classes as $class) {
   \App\$class::creating($closure);
}
```